# npm install - why javascript code in node_modules is in es5

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

After `npm install` I found the code in my node_modules as expected - but it looks different than the code in Github.
Why is that?
How can I get the original es6 code (assuming I want to debug it)?

Example - taken from [material-ui-pickers](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-pickers/blob/master/lib/src/index.js):
**index.js in github**

```
export { default as DatePicker } from './DatePicker';

export { default as TimePicker } from './TimePicker';

export { default as DateTimePicker } from './DateTimePicker';

export { default as MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from './utils/MuiPickersUtilsProvider';
```

**index.js in my node_modules**

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _DatePicker = require('./DatePicker');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'DatePicker', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _interopRequireDefault(_DatePicker).default;
  }
});

var _TimePicker = require('./TimePicker');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'TimePicker', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _interopRequireDefault(_TimePicker).default;
  }
});

var _DateTimePicker = require('./DateTimePicker');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'DateTimePicker', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _interopRequireDefault(_DateTimePicker).default;
  }
});

var _MuiPickersUtilsProvider = require('./utils/MuiPickersUtilsProvider');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'MuiPickersUtilsProvider', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _interopRequireDefault(_MuiPickersUtilsProvider).default;
  }
});

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

Comment: Because many browsers can't handle all the features of es6/7 yet so developers make their modules compatible with them. Also it means that your bundler can run faster as it doesn't need to run the modules through a transpiler when producing your own es5 built app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are built before publishing, that's why it's on ES5. **You should not be touching anything inside node_modules.** The whole idea of having a package manager such as NPM or Yarn is that there is always a **deterministic way of installing the packages**.

I don't know why you'd want to touch a module inside there, but if what you're working is on a PR for that module, you should instead follow they [contribution guidelines](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-pickers#contributing), which is usually "Clone repo, install, write code, submit PR and done".

Of course, if you want to use the code you wrote for that module on your project, then you should read about [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) or [yarn link](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/). That way you can link a module in your local directories, to your project. This will make it easier to develop the functionality you want on the module, and test it on your project.

Comment: Thanks for answering - I have an issue with a specific 3rd party library but I cant debug it - this is why I would like to have its es6 code in my node_modules

Comment: Go to the 3rd party libraries github. There is the ES6 code. I suggest you open an issue describing the problem, and have a discussion with the maintainers about it. If you want to fix it, submit a PR to that repo

Comment: If this worked for you, please consider marking it as the accepted answers so other users can also benefit